# Javascript Tic Tac Toe - Checking if a player has won always returns false

Tags: javascript

Trying to build a JS tic-tac-toe game. I've successfully done this in python previously, but using similar logic I can't seem to get the checkWin function to correctly return whether or not a player has won.

Here is the code

```
var Game = function(){
let board = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], turnCounter;

this.checkWin = function(){ // seems to be an issue with this check win function
    if (
        board[0] == board[1] == board[2] ||
        board[0] == board[3] == board[6] ||
        board[3] == board[4] == board[5] ||
        board[1] == board[4] == board[7] ||
        board[6] == board[7] == board[8] ||
        board[2] == board[5] == board[8] ||
        board[0] == board[4] == board[8] ||
        board[2] == board[4] == board[6]){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

The board array represents a 3x3 grid, 0 top left, 8 in the bottom right. It gets updated to either X or O based on a users selection.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `board[0] == board[1] == board[2]` is resolved as `((board[0] == board[1]) = (true/false)) == board[2]`. The final resolution will usually be false because you're comparing a boolean with a number. Type conversion will happen there, because you're not using a strict comparison, so it is possible that it could return true depending on the truthiness comparison.

Comment: btw, this code will also break after you fix this problem, since an empty board just means `(board[0] === board[1] && board[0] === board[2])`.

Comment: board values are set to their index until replaced by the token of each user, so an empty board never occurs. I had a feeling JS might not play nice with my python logic. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/f9d3f31c208328a97c9e3d16d32f958a) for fun, inspired by this question.

Answer (score 2):

As Tiny Giant said, you're short-circuiting your if statements!

`board[0] == board[1] == board[2]` is equivalent to seeing if the values of `board[0]` and `board[1]` are the same, and then seeing if that boolean (`true`/`false`) is equivalent to the value of `board[2]`

Here is a translation that might work a little better.

```
(board[0] == board[1] && board[1] == board[2]) ||
(board[0] == board[3] && board[3] == board[6]) ||
(board[3] == board[4] && board[4] == board[5]) ||
(board[1] == board[4] && board[4] == board[7]) ||
(board[6] == board[7] && board[7] == board[8]) ||
(board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8]) ||
(board[0] == board[4] && board[4] == board[8]) ||
(board[2] == board[4] && board[4] == board[6])
```

Essentially, I just repeated the middle one: if `a == b` and `b == c` then `a == c`, equivalent to `a == b == c`. Fair warning: this is untested code, I just adjusted it so it wouldn't short-circut.

Comment: This was the change I implemented after I read Tiny Giant's comment and it worked!